# My account wasn't deleted despite the countdown

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I requested my elementary OS account be deleted, and I confirmed it, and the countdown reached 2 hours at 11:30pm BTC. I went back on my computer today, and my account was still active and receiving reputation - I'd passed 2000 overnight.

Is it an issue with global authentication that caused this?

---

<sup>I have contacted the team again so they do / will know.</sup>

Comment: When there is a non-trivial number of votes cast, it requires a human to push a button to make sure that things don't cause problems. In your case, it would cause about 2000 reputation on other users to disappear from the site if the votes aren't transferred(?). Such a change can cause issues (and various 'where did my rep go?' posts).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MichaelT beat me to the explanation by a split second here. :)

Your voting activity was beyond the threshold where we delete users, so your elementaryOS profile was placed into a queue that a human reviews. I just processed your deletion, so you should be all set.

Sorry about the delay and the confusion.

Comment: might be worth it to change the countdown notice to something like "awaiting review" or so to avoid this confusion

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, I need to check how painful that'd be. It keeps coming up, though, so definitely worth looking into.